# Trying to use two connection objects in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle10g

I have created a class `ConnectionManager` with method `getConnection`.
This `getConnection` Method creates a new DB connection to the same DB every time it is invoked. It uses `DriverManager.getConnection()`.
Now, I have created two different connection objects using ConnectionManager.

```
conn1 = ConnectionManager.getConnection()
conn2 = ConnectionManager.getConnection()
```

now if I do this

```
conn2.setAutoCommit(false);
conn1.prepareStatment(somequery);
// ....Excute a set of prepared statments using conn1
conn2.commit(); // or conn2.rollback()
```

Is using two different connection object, one for transaction management and other for statement execution valid?
If yes, will the transaction work the same way as it would work for a single object?

Also, I am using OracleDB

Comment: what do you mean by this - **Is this valid?** Please clarify your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is using two different connection object, one for transaction
>   management and other for statement execution valid? If yes, will the
>   transaction work the same way as it would work for a single object?

No, Its not Valid. Transaction will not work the same way as it would work for a single object.

Both are two different `Connections`, settings done for one `Connection` will not affect settings for other `Connection`- These two are simply two unrelated `Connection` Objects pointing to same database.

Answer (score 0):

`conn1` and `conn2` are two different connections with two different transactions, then:

for `conn2`:

nothing changes because the unique command you send is a `commit` but nothing is changed in your data

for `conn1`:

if `conn1` has `autocommit =true` , all commands sents are committed by the `dmbs` else nothing happen because no one commits your changes.

Comment: Could you be little more elaborate ?? And please give me the final verdict as whether this will work as intended with a single connection object.